# Use of secure 'property' tag in jnlp with Java 7 Update 45

Tags: java, java-web-start

Java 7 Update 45 blocks the use of unsecure property tags. E.g. we use in our jnlp the property "swing.defaultlaf" to set the look and feel. This worked fine until this upgrade. From the Oracle documentation and hints on this website, I've learned that adding "javaws." or "jnlp." to the property name, would make update 45 treat such a property as secure.
My knowledge of Java is not in details, many of our code is generated. I already found out that simply changing my sample property into "jnlp.swing.defaultlaf" does not solve the issue. So I guess I have to get the value of this new property name in my Java code? Can someone supply a sample?
I guess that not all system properties can be changed when the application is already running. How should these property issues be solved?

PS I hate signing the jnlp files. We have more than one and we have daily updates on our SaaS system. All our .jar files are signed, our server and system software is constantly updated and now we also have to sign jnlp files?

Comment: Please use the formatting capabilities of SO.